# a data structure with key as a cluster of words and value as a single word or string

Tags: python, dictionary, reverse

I want to create a data structure that is able to map a cluster or group of words to a single word or string , it can be thought as of a reverse of what a dictionary does in python .

Comment: I am not sure what types for the keys you have in mind, but you could define a class yourself which you use as keys (internally it could store the words as a list of strings, ...) and define a hash function for it. Could you provide an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: well, the question is not clear. What have you tried so far and what exactly do you expect the community to answer?

Comment: Do you want something like `{'a': 'b', 'c': 'b'}`, where `a` and `c` belong to a single group?

Comment: I am looking for something which work as reverse of dictionary Example ["best","possitive","awesome","fantastic"] should act as a key they should map to one value "good"

Comment: a dicitonary with key as list of words and value as a single word or string

Comment: is there any available module or functions in python for this

Comment: In python you can't use a list as key because it is mutable but you can use a tuple of words.

Comment: In dictionary can we use tuple of words as a key ?

Comment: Yes tuple is immutable, so it's hashable so you can use it as a key.

Comment: @ Alex Hall : yes exactly , as i am observing it is not possible with dictionary . So can you suggest some other data structure for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular dict:

```
targetword = "good"
wordmap = {
    "best": targetword,
    "positive": targetword,
    "awesome": targetword,
    "fantastic": targetword
}
```

Comment: That is correct but can it be something like this , wp={ ["best", "possitive","awesome","fantastic"] : "good"] }

Comment: @SagarRajSingh: No.  But you could easily write a conversion function taking your example and turning it into my format.  All you'd have to change in your format is to use `()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: wordpower = { ("best" , "up" , "awesome" , "fantastic" , "happy" , "better" , "best" , "wonderful" , "good" ) : "possitive"}
wordpower1 = { ("worst" , "bad" ,"down" ) : "negative" }
ws= " best and  are the worst"

words=ws.split()
for i in range(0,len(words)):
    if words[i] in wordpower:
        print ("found")
but its not working since none of the time "found" is printed

Comment: can you suggest some other data structure for it that can map more than one key into a single value

Comment: @SagarRajSingh: Please post a new question.  Most people won't see the comments you add here.